# Cant confirm delete with swal on laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

hey guys i have a little probleme with swal condition when the user confirm the delete nothing happen
(swal version 7.0.7)

there is the swal code

```html
<form id="del_type" action="{{ route('admin.type.destroy', $type->id) }}" method="post"style="display: inline">
     {!! method_field('delete') !!}
     {{ csrf_field() }}
<button class="btn btn-danger  delete_type" type="submit" >Supprimer</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(".delete_type").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this)

    //console.info(_this.parent().prop('action'))
    swal({
        title: "Attention",
        text: "Veuillez confirmer la suppression",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Confirmer",
        cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
    }, function(result) {
        if(result) {
            $('#del_type').submit();
        } else {
            swal('cancelled');
        }
    });
});
```

when i click on the delete button it shows the swal with the confirm and cancel button but when you click on confirm nothing happens and there's no submit
(and sorry for my english)

Comment: Try with result.value instead just result `if(result.value) { $('#del_type').submit(); }`

Comment: Can you check like this in your call back function(result) {
                    $('#del_type').submit();
                }

Comment: i resolved the problem guys i used .then and know it's working .then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    _this.parent().submit();
                } else {
                    
                }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official docs, you have to use promise and check `result.value`.

https://sweetalert2.github.io/v7.html

So, try to rewrite it a bit, like that:

```js
Swal({
    title: "Attention",
    text: "Veuillez confirmer la suppression",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Confirmer",
    cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        $('#del_type').submit();
    } else {
        swal('cancelled');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without swal.

```
$(".delete_type").click( function (e) {
    if(!confirm('Do you want to Delete ?')){
            return false;
       }
  $('#del_type').submit();
});
```